# File related Exception classes in C++ or Qt

Tags: c++, exception

Java has file related exception classes.

Do C++ or Qt have similar classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [standard library streams](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/) have two modes:

1. State checking - the programmer must call `good()`, `eof()`, `fail()` or `bad()` to detect problems.
2. Exception throwing - the programmer calls [`exceptions(...)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/exceptions/) to set an exception mask, see the link for an example.

The Qt library typically does not use exceptions, the [`QIODevice`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qiodevice.html) class (and hence `QFile`) will return a `bool` for the success or failure of a call. The error message can be obtained from [`QIODevice::errorString()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qiodevice.html#errorString).

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing c++ (programming language) and Qt (library)...

If You want to use bare C++ then iostreams has ifstream for processing file streams, dunno if it throws exceptions - don't use it tbh... but I'd suggest checking *boost* and *filesystem* library as it has better readable syntax and some samples to get you started: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/filesystem/doc/tutorial.html